# Magento CE18: Cannot save new password nor place order using credit card

Tags: php, magento

I have been getting "Validate class not found from basename 'NotEmpty' error whenever I try to change password or place test orders at our site.
When I check error_log, I see the following errors, but I have no idea what it means...

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Flat_Collection::getAllIdsSql() in /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Category/Tree.php on line 295
```

Does anyone have any clue?

Answer (score 4):

This is a Magento bug.

Without flat tables, `Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()` will return a `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Collection` object, which extends from `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract` which has the `getAllIdsSql()` method.

However, if flat tables are enabled the collection will be a `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Flat_Collection` which does not inherit the `getAllIdsSql()` method, resulting in the error you're seeing.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue/index/id/68

If you have Enterprise support, contact them and they will provide a patch.

#### Edit:

A patch is available: https://gist.github.com/piotrekkaminski/25db530371b900d0d969

Answer (score 0):

This bug has been fixed in Magento Community Edition, version 1.9.1.0.
I would recommend to upgrade your Magento installation to the latest release, which also includes several security patches, as modifying the core is generally considered bad practice, and is going eventually to lead to issues no easy to identify and fix in future.